# Map of bounded types in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm trying to build something like a class registry in Scala where I can grab a class object from a key. 
The point is that I want to ensure my classes to inherit from a common trait.

Something like that :

```
trait GenericTrait{
   def doSomethingCool()
}
trait AbstractRegistry {
  def registry[T <: GenericTrait]:Map[String, Class[T]]
}

class Object1 extends GenericTrait{
   override def doSomethingCool()= println("hello")
}

class Object2 extends GenericTrait{
   override def doSomethingCool()=println("hi")
}

object MyClassRegistry extends AbstractRegistry {
  override def registry[T <: GenericTrait]:Map[String, Class[T]]=Map(
      "obj1" -> classOf[Object1],
      "obj2" -> classOf[Object2]
  )
}
```

But it looks like I missed something because it doesn't compile...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class[A] is [invariant](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/) in A. This basically means that if you have a `Map[String, Class[GenericTrait]]` you cannot put in the map values of type Class[Object1] or Class[Object2]  because they are not subtypes of Class[GenericTrait].

You have to declare an upper type bound `_ <: GenericTrait` on the values of the map so that they become of type "Class[T] where T is a subclass of GenericTrait" . You also have to make T a type parameter of AbstractRegistry and not of the method

```
trait GenericTrait {
  def doSomethingCool()
}

trait AbstractRegistry[T <: GenericTrait] {
  def registry: Map[String, Class[_ <: T]]
}

class Object1 extends GenericTrait {
  override def doSomethingCool() = println("hello")
}

class Object2 extends GenericTrait {
  override def doSomethingCool() = println("hi")
}

object MyClassRegistry extends AbstractRegistry[GenericTrait] {
  override def registry: Map[String, Class[_ <: GenericTrait]] = Map(
    "obj1" -> classOf[Object1],
    "obj2" -> classOf[Object2]
  )
}
```

As you commented, you don't really need the AbstractRegistry type parameter if you don't need to be able to limit your registry subclass to a subtree of GenericTrait descendants.

```
    trait AbstractRegistry {
      def registry: Map[String, Class[_ <: GenericTrait]]
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you !

EDIT :  `def registry: Map[String, Class[_ <: GenericTrait]]` seems to work as well and is even simpler.

Comment: yes, I left the AbstractRegistry type parameter because you put it in your example. It's not really needed, you can only use it to restrict to registry to a certain sub-family of GenericTrait descendants. added that to the answer :)

Comment: "they are not subclasses of Class[GenericTrait]" Nitpick: subtypes, not subclasses.